# Higlight text not working for even rows in html table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have table like below

```
<table class = "gridHover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <label for="searchbox">Search:</label>
            <input type="text" id="searchbox" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>More text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>blah?</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Test ipsum</td>
        <td>Test?</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have text box where i enter text and then it highlights the text in table. My jquery code is as below

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('#searchbox').keyup(
        function(){
            var searchText = $(this).val();
            if (searchText.length > 0){
                $('td:contains(' + searchText +')')
                    .addClass('searchResult'); 
                $('td:not(:contains('+searchText+'))')
                    .removeClass('searchResult');
            }
            else if (searchText.length == 0) {
                $('td.searchResult')
                    .removeClass('searchResult');
            }
        });
});
```

Here is link to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPVcw/134/) to make it more clear and replicate problem.

If you type the text you can see that it will only highlight text in 2nd row i.e odd rows. This is because of the css rule i have like below

```
 .gridHover tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td, .gridHover tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
```

I want to keep this css rule but still want to highlight the rows matching the text. How should i go about it?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. It's working fine for all cells.

Comment: @Siamak.A.M Please see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PPVcw/134/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being affected by *CSS specificity* - the more specific rule in your `tr:odd` style overrides your `.searchResult` style.

You can change your `.searchResult` style so that it also refers to at least the same total set of matching rules as the `tr:odd` style, e.g.:

```
.gridHover tbody tr td.searchResult {
        background-color: #ffa;
}
```

this being more specific than `.gridHover tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td`.

With this rule in place, you can also remove the existing `td.searchResult` rule as it's covered by the above rule.

Comment: i added inline css. See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PPVcw/137/. I added css to each td now. still not working. If you know how to make it work then please can you update my fiddle. Thanks in advance

Comment: That looks great. Also is it possible to make search not case sensitive. Right now you can see that if you type capital S then it higlights only 1st row. Is it possible to make it case insensitive. Hope you understand

Comment: @RameshPatil that's a different question.  Ask (or search for) another question about case insensitivity.

Comment: Using `!important` would also fix this, without needing to make the rule more specific.

Comment: @Dave How to use this !important?

Comment: @Dave FWIW, his existing `td.searchResult` style isn't specific enough (it also highlights the `<th>`) so adding `!important` doesn't help much.

Comment: @Alnitak Many thanks. I wish i could upvote but not enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I updated fiddle [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/PPVcw/138/) see it

just add the class u need on the odd (td,th)

and  added Case-Insensitive
see this [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/)
js:

```
 jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
         return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
             .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
       };
       jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
         return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
             .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
       };
```

css:

```
td {
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 0.4em 1em;

}

td.searchResult {
background-color: #ffa;
 }



.gridHover tbody {
 cursor: default;
 }
.gridHover tbody tr:hover td,.gridHover tbody tr:hover th {
 background-color: #fafad2;
 }


  .gridHover tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td, .gridHover tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th {
background-color: #f9f9f9;
 }
    .gridHover tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td.searchResult, .gridHover tbody tr:nth-   child(odd)    th.searchResult {
  background-color: #ffa;
   }
  .head td
   {
  background-color: white;    
   }
```

Comment: That looks great. Also is it possible to make search not case sensitive. Right now you can see that if you type capital S then it higlights only 1st row. Is it possible to make it case insensitive. Hope you understand.

Comment: this is more complicated than it needs to be.  You _only_ need a single rule containing `.searchResult` that is more specific than any other rule.  With that rule present, the general `td.searchResult` rule is unnecessary.

Comment: @Alnitak Didnt quite understood what you meant here.

Comment: @RameshPatil I'm trying to say that one _single_ rule mentioning `.searchResult` is enough, whereas this answer still contains an (incorrect) general rule and another _very_ specific rule that is actually over specific.

Comment: Many thanks Mahmoude. I wish i could upvote but not enough reputation.

Comment: @RameshPatil Okay Man its Okay I edit my Answer check the link again ;)

Comment: When You have reputation dont forget me :b @RameshPatil

Comment: did u check this link http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/PPVcw/138/ or not @RameshPatil

Comment: @MahmoudeElghandour yes i used something similar to this and it worked for me http://jsfiddle.net/nJgWD/18/